# How to use Google Scripts with Google Sheets to send an email 3 days before a defined date?

Tags: java, scripting, google-sheets

I modified Google's Mail Merger example to create a Google Spreadsheet/Script that I would like to have send an email 3 days before a client's rental due date. I have a cell set up to take the rental due date inputted by the user and subtract it by today's date.

I then have a if statement running to check if that cell is equal to 3 and if so send an email with MailApp. But for some reason it does not seem to work and when I try and Logger.log the variable comes back undefined. I am really new to Google Scripts and Sheets so I apologize if I am being vague at all or not understanding something fundamental.

Here is [a link to the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m3rt20Ge44m8tnqhuaejHXjwE8bJCfu3XgPOG9M_k-8/edit?usp=sharing), you just have to go to tools/script editor to see the script.

```
function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, dataSheet.getMaxRows() - 1, 7);

  var templateSheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var emailTemplate = templateSheet.getRange("A1").getValue();

  // Create one JavaScript object per row of data.
  var objects = getRowsData(dataSheet, dataRange);

  // For every row object, create a personalized email from a template and send
  // it to the appropriate person.
  for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
    // Get a row object
    var rowData = objects[i];

    // Generate a personalized email.
    // Given a template string, replace markers (for instance ${"First Name"}) with
    // the corresponding value in a row object (for instance rowData.firstName).
    var emailText = fillInTemplateFromObject(emailTemplate, rowData);
    var emailSubject = "Your Renty Rental is Due Soon!";
    var timeTill = objects[i][6];
    Logger.log(timeTill);
    if (timeTill == 3) {
      MailApp.sendEmail(rowData.emailAddress, emailSubject, emailText);
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried dumping `objects` to see its internal structure? I am not much of a JS person, but I believe there are libraries/snippets available for dumping complex vars in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails)

And assuming you just wanted to send simple email to the recipient, I made a more simple email function for you;

```
function sendMail(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   //Get the active Spreadsheet
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');     //Get the sheet by name, Sheet1 as example
  var startRow = 2;     //We start process things from row 2
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();    //Get the last row of data to be processed
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();  // Get the last column of data to be processed
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,lastCol);  //Fetch the range
  var data = range.getValues();   //Get the values inside the range
      for (var i = 0;i<data.length;i++)   //Iterate values
        var row = data[i];   //Set up variable for easier retrieve data to be processed and more understandable by human
        var FirstName = row[1];  //Column B
        var LastName = row[2];   //Column C
        var emailAddress = row[3];  //Column D
        var dueDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[4]),'GMT+0800','MM/dd/yyyy');   //Column E. Utilities format so the date won't be in long values
        var timer = row[6];  //Column G
        var msg = 'Hello '+FirstName+' '+LastName+'<br><br>'   // Your templates
                 +'This is a test mail '+dueDate+'<br><br>'
                 +'Bla bla bla<br>'
                 +'Another lines of texts<br><br>'
                 +'Another lines of texts<br><br>'
                 +'Thank You<br><br>'
                 +'OH!! I like Banana.';
            if(timer == 3){   //Set up the condition
            GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,'Your Renty Rental is Due Soon!',msg,{htmlBody:msg});   //Send the email to the recipient
            sheet.getRange(startRow+i,7).setNote('Email Sent');  //Set note on column 'G' 
            }
}
```

For the trigger to run everyday, go to "Resource", click "Current Project Trigger". Set new project trigger with "function sendMail", "Time driven", "Day timer", "time you want the script to run".

If anything in doubt, comment it here.

---

Fixed:
I forgot the {} behind "For" loop;

```
function sendMail(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   //Get the active Spreadsheet
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');     //Get the sheet by name, Sheet1 as example
  var startRow = 2;     //We start process things from row 2
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();    //Get the last row of data to be processed
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();  // Get the last column of data to be processed
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,lastCol);  //Fetch the range
  var data = range.getValues();   //Get the values inside the range
      for (var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){   //Iterate values
        var row = data[i];   //Set up variable for easier retrieve data to be processed and more understandable by human
        var FirstName = row[1];  //Column B
        var LastName = row[2];   //Column C
        var emailAddress = row[3];  //Column D
        var dueDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[4]),'GMT+0800','dd/MM/yyyy');   //Column E. Utilities format so the date won't be in long values
        var timer = row[6];  //Column G
        var msg = 'Hello '+FirstName+' '+LastName+'<br><br>'   // Your templates
                 +'This is a test mail '+dueDate+'<br><br>'
                 +'Bla bla bla<br>'
                 +'Another lines of texts<br><br>'
                 +'Another lines of texts<br><br>'
                 +'Thank You<br><br>'
                 +'OH!! I like Banana.';
            if(timer ==3){   //Set up the condition
            GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,'Your Renty Rental is Due Soon!',msg,{htmlBody:msg})   //Send the email to the recipient
            sheet.getRange(startRow+i,7).setNote('Email Sent');  //Set note on column 'G' 
            SpreadsheetApp.flush
            }
    }
};
```

Comment: Hmm.. this does not seem to work I tried using it with my current spreadsheet and it did nothing. Did it work when you tested it?

Comment: There are few clarification i need to ask you. Will make some comment on the sheet you shared before, so i can help you.

Comment: Fixed it for you. Forgot the {} behind the "For" loop. On the GMT+0800, change it to GMT-0800. I used GMT+0800 to test it according to my timezone

Comment: That worked! Thank you SO much for your help! I really appreciate it.